Properly typing a function with Callable argument
I have an async function that takes as an input a list that can contain values of CustomType1 or CustomType2. It also takes in a function as its second argument. For now I'm just using Callable[..., Coroutine[Any, Any, CustomType3]] but I would like to properly type the function argument.
    async def func1(
      arg1: list[CustomType1 | CustomType2],
      fn: Callable[..., Coroutine[Any, Any, CustomType3]],
      **kwargs: str,
      ) -> list[CustomType3]:
      

      return list(await asyncio.gather(*(fn(value, **kwargs) for value in arg1)))

I have two functions with different signatures that can be passed to func1:
async def fn1(
   arg1: CustomType1,
   arg2: str,
   arg3: str
) -> CustomType3: ...


async def fn2(
   arg1: CustomType2
) -> CustomType3: ...

I tried doing
fn: Callable[[CustomType1 | CustomType2, ...], Coroutine[Any, Any, CustomType3]]
but mypy throws these errors:

Unexpected "...": at the line where I type the fn argument
Too few arguments: at the line where func1 returns
Argument 2 to "func1" has incompatible type "Callable[[CustomType1, str, str], Coroutine[Any, Any, CustomType3]]"; expected "Callable[[CustomType1 | CustomType2, Any], Coroutine[Any, Any, CustomType3]]": wherever I call fn1 and a similiar error at my calls to fn2.

I also tried going through https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols but I think I'm a bit over my head. Looking for any pointers on how to approach this.
(I'm using mypy version 1.10.0 if that's relevant)

I'm not sure you can restrict to those two specific signatures. Is it strictly necessary? Perhaps just a generic ParamSpec instead, like this?

I agree with @STerliakov. But as a side note, returning a list could significantly hurt throughput / performance of the caller. This is because if the first coroutine completes before the second, caller has to wait for the second before accessing first's result using your return type. It may be a better idea to return an async generator, where items can be processed incrementally. Caller can turn async generator to list if they'd like themselves.

Couple of things here worth noting:

You can use Protocol to define more specific function signatures than the Callable interface.
All function signatures must match when making to a function - even if you know there are no additional arguments, on this line: fn(value, **kwargs), the function needs to know how to handle any additional arguments provided
TypeVar can be used to say these two parts of a function must match, and must be subject to certain constraints.

Part 1: The lite answer
The below solution solves the problem in a pretty elegent way that for most use cases would be fine:
See below:

from typing import Protocol, TypeVar
import asyncio

class CustomType1:
    pass

class CustomType2:
    pass

class CustomType3:
    pass

T = TypeVar("T", CustomType1, CustomType2)
class CallableType[T](Protocol):
    async def __call__(self, arg1: T, **kwargs: str) -> CustomType3:
        ...

async def func1(
    arg1: list[T],
    fn: CallableType[T],
    **kwargs: str,
    ) -> list[CustomType3]:
    return list(await asyncio.gather(*(fn(value, **kwargs) for value in arg1)))

async def fn1(
   arg1: CustomType1,
    **kwargs: str,
) -> CustomType3: ...


async def fn2(
   arg1: CustomType2,
    **kwargs: str,
) -> CustomType3: ...

async def test():
    await func1([CustomType1()], fn1)

The only downside to this is that the kwargs are now untyped, so this is what I resolve in part 2.
Part 2: Specifying kwargs
Let's say that getting type checking on the kwargs is important. You actually would give yourself a much easier time, just moving the kwargs into a separate object. I would suggest moving these into function specific objects like so:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional, Protocol, TypeVar, cast, overload
import asyncio

class CustomType1:
    pass

class CustomType2:
    pass

class CustomType3:
    pass

T = TypeVar("T", CustomType1, CustomType2)
FuncArgs = TypeVar("FuncArgs")
class CallableType1[T, FuncArgs](Protocol):
    async def __call__(self, arg1: T, function_args: FuncArgs) -> CustomType3:
        ...

class CallableType2[T](Protocol):
    async def __call__(self, arg1: T) -> CustomType3:
        ...

@overload
async def func1(
    arg1: list[T],
    fn: CallableType2[T],
) -> list[CustomType3]:
    ...

@overload
async def func1(
    arg1: list[T],
    fn: CallableType1[T, FuncArgs],
    function_args: FuncArgs,
) -> list[CustomType3]:
    ...

async def func1(
    arg1: list[T],
    fn: CallableType1[T, FuncArgs] | CallableType2[T],
    function_args: Optional[FuncArgs] = None,
    ) -> list[CustomType3]:
    if function_args is None:
        fn = cast(CallableType2[T], fn) # Cast is viable as is based on overload
        return list(await asyncio.gather(*(fn(value) for value in arg1)))
    else:
        fn = cast(CallableType1[T, FuncArgs], fn) # Cast is viable as is based on overload
        return list(await asyncio.gather(*(fn(value, function_args) for value in arg1)))

@dataclass
class fn1Args:
   arg2: str
   arg3: str

async def fn1(
   arg1: CustomType1,
   function_args: fn1Args,
) -> CustomType3: ...


async def fn2(
   arg1: CustomType2
) -> CustomType3: ...

async def test():
    await func1([CustomType1()], fn1, fn1Args('test', 'test2'))
    await func1([CustomType2()], fn2)

Hope this helps!
